# How to delete a database application in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I have created a database application in oracle application express and don't know  how to delete it because there is no delete button to remove it

Answer (score 7):

Both for Apex 4.2 and Apex 5.0:

1. Edit the application.
2. On the right of the screen you will find a list named "Tasks".
3. This list has an entry "Delete application".

**Apex 4.2:**
[image: Apex 4.2: Application > tasks > delete]

**Apex 5:**
[image: Apex 5.0: Application > tasks > delete]

Comment: Thank u...can u tell me how to kill session 'alter system kill session 'sid,serial#' in oracle apex..please help me out ..